# Racket - turns symbols in quoted list to lowercase automatically

Tags: list, racket, quote, r5rs

I have the following program in Racket with the language set to "determine from source" and output syntax set to "write":

```
#lang r5rs
(define g '((w C C) (x A C) (y A B) (z B C)))
```

When I run it and type in the interactive prompt

```
> g
```

I get

```
{{w c c} {x a c} {y a b} {z b c}}
```

However, when I type the list directly to the prompt I get

```
> '((w C C) (x A C) (y A B) (z B C))
{{w C C} {x A C} {y A B} {z B C}}
```

How can I prevent Racket from turning the symbols to lowercase?

Comment: You can use `(define g #cs'((w C C) (x A C) (y A B) (z B C)))` (mind the `#cs` prefix which forces case sensitivity) but that's kinda hacky and there *must* be a better solution.

Comment: r5rs is not Racket, it's a Scheme standard. For Racket you would have to type `#lang racket` in "DrRacket" which is an IDE that supports multiple languages.

Comment: Yes, I meant I'm using R5RS in DrRacket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The R5RS standard requires the reader to hand symbols without case sensitivity. Most R5RS implementations will convert symbols with upper case symbols into lower case. If you need to produce a symbol with upper case letters, you need to use `string->symbol`.

```
> (string->symbol "Hello")
Hello
```

Since many Scheme implementations supported case sensitivity, later standards changed the default to case sensitivity.

See the (first!) question in the Scheme FAQ for a longer explanation:

http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-language